# How does nodejs's lchown internal code work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I'm currently trying to learn how's nodejs's lchown changes the UID and GUID if the pathname specified is a symbolic link. The problem is that I'm absolutely confused since it seems to be calling itself in the line of code below:

```
binding.lchown(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path), uid, gid, req);
```

Link to the internal code:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/10eaf6a09feee78275d5c1f84ce46815d8a8772f/lib/fs.js#L1084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not calling itself. It is calling `binding.lchown`.

I know nothing about Node.js internals but from the looks of the code, it seems clear that [`binding` is a reference to some internal module, maybe written in C or C++](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L46):

```
const binding = internalBinding('fs');
```

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a neat trick to see the contents of the internal module?

Comment: As I wrote, I know nothing about Node.js internals, I don't know C++, and I don't know C, so I am entirely the wrong person to ask. I could only search and guess, the same as you, e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=lchown+filename%3Afs.*

Comment: No worries. Very grateful for the help.